# Nextjs as an public API server preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

Tags: javascript, next.js, cors

I am creating  public APIs using nextjs this is my next.config.js file

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                // matching all API routes
                source: "/api/:path*",
                headers: [
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" }, // replace this your actual origin
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT" },
                    { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version, Authorization" },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

and this is my middleware file

```
// Check if the request path starts with "/api/auth" or "/api/admin"
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api/auth") || request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/api/admin")) {
    if (request.method === "OPTIONS") {
      return NextResponse.json({}); // Handle preflight OPTIONS request
    }
```

Everything works fine on localhost there is no cors error on localhost but in production when origin of my nextjs API server changes I got this error:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

As in localhost everything is working fine I want that in production also it should work fine.